# Howto: Get ALL nearby places

Tags: facebook, api

**The Situation**
I want to rebuild some parts of the FB place checking into my own application.

**The Challenge 1**
How to get all nearby places? Facebook wants to have a query to look. But I want ALL nearby places.

Could this be a workaround?

```
        $places = $this->facebook->search( 'place', '%%', array('center'=>'53.559562, 9.964266', 'distance'=>'10000' ,'access_token' => $access_token));
```

Answer (score 6):

Seems like you can just omit the query field if using the Graph API
with:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=pizza&type=place&center=lat,long&distance=1000

without:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=lat,long&distance=1000

you can just leave it out entirely.

with specific number of results:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=lat,long&distance=1000&limit=100